# Problem on Dispatching Actions in React Using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui

I have a dialog that is reusable. I have just ONE dialog for confirmation in logging out and for deleting.
My problem is on the logging out, once i confirm the logout, the action that is firing is the deletion.
I have put a console.log `console.log("SUCCESS LOGOUT")` `console.log("DELETE USER SUCCESS");` to see if what action successfully fires and its the delete action. How will i fix this? Thank you.

SEE THIS LINK

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/reusable-dialog-4kosb)

**Dialog**

```
    const ReusableDialog = ({
      title,
      details,
      open,
      type,
      onAgree,
      onDisagree
    }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <Dialog
            open={open}
            TransitionComponent={Transition}
            keepMounted
            onClose={onDisagree}
            aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-slide-title"
            aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
          >
            <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-slide-title">
              <span>
                Are you sure you want to {title} {details?.name}
              </span>
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogActions>
              <Button variant="contained" size="small" onClick={onDisagree}>
                Cancel
              </Button>
              <Button variant="contained" size="small" onClick={onAgree}>
                Confirm
              </Button>
            </DialogActions>
          </Dialog>
        </div>
      );
    };

export default ReusableDialog;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two dialog's are opening at once.
As you are using the **global single** state for dialog, two dialogss are being opened one from the users.js and one from navbar.js.

They are overlapping hence you can't see them add a big title to one of them and then see.

Why would you want a Global state for dialog?
**A local state should solve your problem.**

Comment: he is right, using a global state you open both dialogs with same values, but the user's overlaps the navbar's. if you want to open only a specific one you should use a local state to that specific dialog. on the other hand if you want to have only one dialog at your app, maybe you should consider remove those at navbar and at user, and add it to your root, if so, pass the confirm handler as well as param to dialog.

Comment: just to be clear: though when you click the navbar you see navbar's text at dialog you are actually seeing user's dialog, since you are passing the same text for both. no matter where you click you have user's dialog at front and navbar's at back.